# Only admin can see comments on post or page

Tags: comments

Odd situation. Only members with 'admin' role can see comments on a post or page. So, I can set up a new role with all of the admin capabilities but they can't see comments on a post or page - even their own. I must have done something. can anyone suggest a way to solve this? By the way there is no plugin conflict thing (unless something wrote something to the DB) as I've tried by deactivating all plugins.